# What is the difference between in_array() and @in_array() in php?

Tags: php, arrays

can you please help i just want to know why we use @in_array function.

```
$name = array("ravi", "ram", "rani", 87); 


if (in_array("ravi", $name, TRUE)){

}

if (@in_array("ravi", $name, TRUE)){

}
```

Comment: The @("at") symbol just suppresses errors in general

Comment: Please read the docs before asking http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: There is almost never a reason to use the `@` operator

Comment: there is! lazyness :) @Philipp

Comment: @Philipp I've found it very useful when writing functions that have to handle a wide range of input data, including nulls and unassigned values. It's cleaner to check for those issues once inside the function and handle it then, than to wrap many calls to that function with `if` statements. The '@' symbol lets me do that without spamming the error logs.

Answer (score 1):

The "@" symbol turn off the errors. It is not a good idea to use it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Error Control Operators
PHP supports one error control operator:

```
 the at sign (@
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php